# Ajax json ссылка из параметров data-href

Tags: jquery, json, php, html5, html5-history-api

Есть меню

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked main-menu mainmenu_user">
<li class="active"><a href="/settings/" data-history="/settings/"  data-href="/ajax/settings.php"><span class="hidden-tablet"> Настройки</span></a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="/settings/" data-history="/settings2/"  data-href="/ajax/settings2.php"><span class="hidden-tablet"> Настройки2</span></a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="/settings/" data-history="/settings3/" data-href="/ajax/settings3.php"><span class="hidden-tablet"> Настройки3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Пытаюсь написать скрипт который бы брал значение из data-href и получал оттуда json, еще хотелось бы чтобы вставлял параметр data-history в адресную строку, но это я пока не понял как делать

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mainmenu_user li a').click(function(){
        var url_ajax = $(".mainmenu_user li a").data("href");
        $.getJSON(url_ajax, {}, function(json){
            $('.content').html('');
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если для современных браузеров, то [history.pushState](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)(null, null, link.href);

Для всех остальных можно подключить polyfill, например — [HTML5-History-API](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API)

Пример:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mainmenu_user li a').click(function(evt/**$.Event*/){
        evt.preventDefault();

        var ajaxUrl = $(this).data("href");
        var historyUrl = $(this).data('history');

        history.pushState(null, null, historyUrl);

        $.getJSON(ajaxUrl, {}, function(json){
            /* __ */
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Дело в том, что пока даже ajax не срабатывает с данным скриптом.
Страница перезагружается, консоль пустая.

Comment: :] Взял за основу ваш срипт и не проверил, поправил его. http://jsfiddle.net/6Wfk4/

Comment: А как еще можно у данного пункта меню снять класс active а у нового подставить?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6Wfk4/1/ — так пойдет?

Comment: да, спасибо огромное